# How can I inject the prisma io module using inversify in my node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, prisma, inversifyjs

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to do dependency injection operations with a node.js project, but I don't know how to use the inversify module with prisma.

I did a lot of research on the internet, but I could not find a clear answer about this, but I also provided research with artificial intelligence, I think there is no clear standard.

Comment: Could you please update the question to include more details about what you're trying to accomplish as well as some potential code examples of what you've tried?
The way the question is worded currently is not very clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @MattHatcher I think the question is very clear I am developing a backend application with this project for the first time in my life and as far as I understand, you are doing dependency injection with inversify, but I am asking how to use it with prisma because I do not know how to inject the prisma client in the repository layer because there is no clear statement about it on the internet, so I asked here :)

Comment: We don't know how you're using Prisma currently, we don't know how you have your project setup, we don't know how you're setting up Inversify, etc. We don't know what you've tried, what you've come across, we don't even know how you're setting up your `injectable` classes. You could have different abstractions we don't even consider when answering. These are the sorts of details needed to help resolve your specific situation because you're right, there's no specific documentation about Prisma with Inversify directly, which means we have to be the documentation for it. That's why it's not clear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.